# Running event handler once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a button in react that performs a toggle action to a boolean.
But I figure out that the button can be used to set and unset the state as a toggle can.
But I want to change the state only one time. Is that another function instead of the toggle to perform what I want?

```
<button onClick={() => toggleDisabled(prevState => !prevState ) }> End your turn </button>
```

Comment: You want to disable the button once toggleDisabled is true?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to permit the re-enabling after clicking again the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the state name is toggle, make use of the disabled prop for button.

```
<button disabled={toggle} onClick={() => toggleDisabled(prevState => !prevState ) }> End your turn </button>
```

Comment: Instead of toggleDisabled variable, I use a boolean variable to store the state and it's work.

Comment: <button disabled={block} onClick={() => toggleDisabled(prevState => !prevState ) }> End your turn </button>

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer. Great to know that it worked!